# Convergence of the real infinite series $\sum \frac{n!e^{n}}{n^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to check the convergence of the real infinite  series  $\sum \frac{n!e^{n}}{n^{n}}$. My problem is  i tried for it ratio and root test both but both failed as in both case limit comes to $1$. Please give me a hint for its convergence.Thaks a lot.

Comment: The series does not converge.

Comment: How please give some hint.....

Comment: Use Stirling's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: I want some simple solution .......

Comment: Yes it's really very nice thanks a lot.....